# Java Regex pattern skip empty lines

Tags: java, regex

I am new in Java and I would appreciate a bit of help.
I have a file with a few empty lines in between. With my current pattern, I can only get in the first 4 lines and then I cannot reach the rest cause it brings an  Error: null.
The result of the code is only the 4 first lines of the file as you can see them in the picture.
Is there a regex to SKIP empty lines in order to avoid getting a NULL value?

My current pattern and code look like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^T20.*|^SPE.*|T20.*|SPE.*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(buchung.TOOLS_Kommentar);
boolean bFind = matcher.find();
String res = matcher.group();

for(Buchungen b : buchungsListe) {
    if(b.TOOLS_Kommentar.equals(res)) {
        b.TOOLS_JiraTicket = res;
    } else {
        b.TOOLS_JiraTicket = "";
    }
}
```

[File picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3dlz.png)

```html
0000             0000000000 0000000000                                       001     T20-1513  El                                                                                                                                                                          
0000             0000000000 0000000000                                       001     T20-1513  El                                                                                                                                                                          
0000             0000000000 0000000000                                       001     T20-1513  El                                                                                                                                                                           
0000             0000000000 0000000000                                       001     T20-1513                                                                                                                                                                         
0000000000 0000000000                                       001                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0000000000 0000000000                                       001                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0000000000 0000000000                                       001                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0000000000 0000000000                                       001                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0000000000 0000000000                                       001                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0000000000 0000000000                                       001                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0000000000 0000000000                                       001                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0000000000 0000000000                                       001                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0000000000 0000000000                                       001                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0000000000 0000000000                                       001                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0001             0000000000 0000000000                                       001     Migratio                                                                                                                                                                                        
0001             0000000000 0000000000                                       001     Migratio                                                                                                                                                                                        
0000000000 0000000000                                       001     Upgrade                                                                                                                                                                                               
0000000000 0000000000                                       001     Upgrade                                                                                                                                                                                                 
0000000000 0000000000                                       001     Upgrade
0000000000 0000000000                                       001     Upgrade
0000000000 0000000000                                       001                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0000000000 0000000000                                       001                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0000000000 0000000000                                       001     Git                                                                                                                                                                                                
0000000000 0000000000                                       001     Git                                                                                                                                                                                                     
0000000000 0000000000                                       001     SPE-000                                                                                                                                                                                                       
0000000000 0000000000                                       001     SPE-000
```

Comment: Why don't you check for null? Btw, you can write your pattern as `.*\\b(?:T20|SPE).*`

Comment: Thank you. How can I check for null? you mean in the regex or in an if statement?

Comment: You could check for `matcher.find()` like this for example https://ideone.com/KcVJlE

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time. I tried this, but this brings nothing at all, not even the 4 first lines.

Comment: I really have a hard time understanding your requirements for the matches, could you add your file to parse at least with a few lines as text in your question as well, please?

Comment: I don't know which part of of your code returns null, but you can start with `if (matcher.find()) {`  and checks like `if (null != b.TOOLS_Kommentar && b.TOOLS_Kommentar.equals(res)) {` What can be the possible values of `res`?

Comment: Use String trim. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-trim-method-example/

Comment: hey @Thefourthbird, i tried that. doesnt make a difference. .res is basically the matcher.group() result, meaning it should bring all the lines that contain either T20 OR SPE.

Comment: hey @DavidTejuosho thanks for the comment, I tried that too and it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your contributions, I managed to make it work by going through all the lines first and then making a filter to see if something was null or not and then to give the right values if not.
So the regex that I made use in the end was `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*");`